# Python mocking requests.get content and iter_lines()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

I am trying to mock the streamed requests.get function for one object that uses it internally.

I particularly need to test following methods:

```
class MyObject(object)
    def __iter__(self):
        payload = {"op": "OPEN"}
        response = requests.get("http://" + self.parsed_uri.uri_path, params=payload, stream=True)
        return response.iter_lines()

    def read(self, size=None):
        if not size or size < 0:
            payload = {"op": "OPEN", "offset": self.offset}
            self.offset = 0
        else:
            payload = {"op": "OPEN", "offset": self.offset, "length": size}
            self.offset = self.offset + size
        response = requests.get("http://" + self.parsed_uri.uri_path, params=payload, stream=True)
        return response.content
```

I need `requests.get` to return me something like "abc\n123"

And then my test method should look like:

```
@mock.patch('requests.get', mock.Mock(side_effect=mocked_requests_get))
def test_iter(self, mock_get):
    object = MyObject(ParseUri("http://host/path"))
    self.assertEqual(object.next(), "abc")
    self.assertEqual(object.next(), "123")

@mock.patch('requests.get', mock.Mock(side_effect=mocked_requests_get))
def test_read(self, mock_get):
    object = MyObject(ParseUri("http://host/path"))
    self.assertEqual(object.read, "abc\n123")
```

I am trying to implement the mocked_requests_get, but unfortunately I can't make it work. Is it possible to use mock library this way? How should the `mocked_requests_get` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD. Can't say what's really wrong with your code without full example. How I solves this with `responses` module:

```
import requests
import unittest
import responses


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri

    def __iter__(self):
        payload = {"op": "OPEN"}
        response = requests.get("http://" + self.uri, params=payload,
                                stream=True)
        return response.iter_lines()


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @responses.activate
    def test_iter_lines(self):
        responses.add(responses.GET, "http://local.host/", body='abc\n123')
        r = iter(Foo("local.host"))
        self.assertEqual(r.next(), "abc")
        self.assertEqual(r.next(), "123")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

P.S. Maybe you want to return iterator before call this?

```
self.assertEqual(object.next(), "123")
```

Comment: It just contains `self.offset`, `self.parsed_uri`, nothing else.

Comment: You mean `__init__`? What about `__next__`?

Comment: Thank you using `responses` library worked for me. Now the only problem is that it returns bytes string in python 3 `b"abc"` and normal string in Python 2 `"abc"`.